# TypeORM - Query OneToMany related entities with TypeORM Repository

Tags: postgresql, relationship, one-to-many, typeorm

I just trying to query a OneToMany related entities but, in this query, i need to get eager loaded data from Entity2 with query in Entity1.

Example:

I have those entities:

```
//Entity1

@Entity('roles')
export class Role {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.role)
    users: User[];
}


//Entity2

export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    name: string;

    @Column('uuid')
    role_id: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => Role, role => role.users)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'role_id' })
    role: Role;
}
```

So, im trying to make a query like this:

```
const rolesRepository = getRepository(Role);

rolesRepository.find({
  where: {
    // user's name
    name: ILike("%john%")
  },
  relations: ['users']
});
```

I need to use user's name to find all roles who have users with name containing "John" and get role and user data (eager load) like:

```
Role: {
  id: '6fa6fa8b-f0e1-48bf-b0ec-61eb35585eba',
  title: 'Pathfinder',
  users: [
    {
      id: 'c9097d7d-b83b-412b-9c81-6a918c07e360',
      name: 'John Doe',
      role_id: '6fa6fa8b-f0e1-48bf-b0ec-61eb35585eba'
    },
    {
      id: 'ed1fffb0-dae5-46ce-83ce-38b379483c7f',
      name: 'Johnny',
      role_id: '6fa6fa8b-f0e1-48bf-b0ec-61eb35585eba'
    }
  ]
}
```

I dont want to use `{ eager: true }` in the entity because i just need one single query using eager loading (using in the entity i will have over-fetching).

This isn't working and i know it doesn't make sense to do a query that way. I just did it to understand the purpose.

Database: Postgres